# I believe I have a successful build with heroku CLI, but I still get application error at URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mlab

I can't wrap my head around why my node/express app is not working in Heroku. I believe I've tried all the suggestions in the docs, and the logs seems to be unhelpful to me... any ideas? I only have post routes... and no frontend engine, but postman doesnt work either...

heroku logs tail...

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-everglades-26713.herokuapp.com 
request_id=6a951e0f-b61f-4773-88da-50ee60233767 fwd="73.95.132.206" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

at git push heroku master

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 362 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (disabled)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_a32a25aa8fefa1e63392a939011c6fa3/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_a32a25aa8fefa1e63392a939011c6fa3/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
remote:        added 213 packages in 5.932s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Skipping cache save (disabled by config)
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'true'
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 20.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://murmuring-everglades-26713.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-everglades-26713.git
   7ccf581..a5444dc  master -> master
```

public git hub here: https://github.com/joha0033/OAuth

Comment: do you have any environmental variables? secret keys or whatever? make sure you add those in for heroku as well

Comment: In the process now, do you have to add/commit/push after you after you make heroku config changes? going to anyways, but just curious. And I know Heroku can be sensative, but can an undefined env variable crash an app? I think that would be in a log somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

it **WAS** the env variables... i understand why I need to tell heroku, but don't see how that wouldn't show up in the logs somewhere... I had about 12 env variables through out, so yea.

FIX: while in app directory/root

```
$ heroku config:set JWT_SECRET=[your secret]
$ heroku config:set GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=[############]
$ heroku config:set FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=[########}
```

plus about a dozen more... works in postman, expected cannot GET/ in browser,

I have learned SO much about heroku and node.js today...

thank you @JSilv